# Dataframe to_sql waiting for a long time when a table is already present

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

I am using the code below to recreate the table and load data. When there is no data , the code runs successfully and the table gets created with data. When I run it the second time , the code keeps waiting for executing this line. I am ending up forcefully exiting after waiting for 10-15 minutes. I am assuming it is unable to drop the table. What could be causing this behavior?

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
df_to_write.to_sql(TABLE, con=self.data_store.engine, schema=SCHEMA, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

Comment: Hard to say out of context. A common problem is a lock because the table is currently opened in another cursor. The SQL engine tries to put an exclusive lock before executing a DDL statement like `DROP TABLE`, and waits for any cursor using the table to be closed.

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta! I think that's exactly the case. I did a df read before this statement. When I commented that out , this worked fine.

Comment: @SergeBallesta  I have updated the code. I am trying to reuse the same connection object though. Doesn't read_sql close the connection?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I passed SQLAlchemy engine instead of connection to read_sql function and that seemed to make it work. I'm not sure why the table gets locked when connection object is passed!

Comment: Unsure of it either. But I think that you can now post an answer to that question for future readers.

Comment: Sure @SergeBallesta , Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SergeBallesta mentioned in the comments it seemed to cause due to a locked table.

I was originally passing postgresql connection object to read_sql function. This cause the to_sql function to wait forever.

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
df_to_write.to_sql(TABLE, con=engine, schema=SCHEMA, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

When I replaced the connection with SQLAlchemy Engine , the to_sql statement started working as expected without locking the table.

```
df = pd.read_sql(engine, connection)
df_to_write.to_sql(TABLE, con=engine, schema=SCHEMA, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, what is SCHEMA for ? What I m supposed to have in?

Comment: @PhilippeHaumesser Schema is the DB schema where your tables reside in postgresql db. Let me know if you have any further questions!